# Lookup both horizontally and vertically to match column headers with row headers

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet like this:

```
Date|101|102|103|104|
---------------------
1/1 | A |   |   |   |
1/2 |   | A |   |   |
1/3 |   |   |   |   |
1/4 |   |   |   | A |
1/5 |   |   | A |   |
```

Then on a second sheet, I would like to fill in the following question marks:

```
ID  | DateA
-----------
101 |  ?
102 |  ?
103 |  ?
```

I can identify the column on sheet 1 for each ID on sheet 2 using
=match(A2,Sheet1!1:1,FALSE)

But I haven't been able to figure out how to then feed this into a second match a la
=match("A",Sheet1!?results from above would go here to select the right column?,FALSE)

I have been looking at the indirect functions and address functions but it is not clear to me that they will do what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the Date column of Sheet1 is column A, and the table with "A" letters is in columns B-Z, the following performs the lookup:

```
=filter(Sheet1!A$2:A, filter(Sheet5!B$2:Z, Sheet5!B$1:Z$1 = A2) = "A")
```

The idea is that the inner `filter` picks the column where the ID number of interest (in A2 of the current sheet) is in the top row. The outer `filter` then picks the date from column A that corresponds to letter "A" in the table.

The above assumes you have one match for each ID. If there happen to be multiple dates, there are two options:

- wrap the formula in `=transpose(...)`, so that the results will appear as a row of dates
- wrap the formula in `=array_constrain(...)`, so that only the first match will appear.

Comment: Thanks so much! For whatever it is worth to someone else who might benefit from this excellent answer, Sheet1 and Sheet5 above can/should refer to the same sheet (Sheet1 for me, but could be anything).